# Retrieve arguments using RtlVirtualUnwind api

Tags: c, windows, arguments, stack, frame

Is it possible to retrieve function arguments of all frames in a call stack using RTLVirtualUnwind windows API ?

Platform :: win64

Arguments are passed in RCX,RDX,R8,R9 which are volatile registers...between function calls the values in these registers are destroyed ...so these are stored some where with respect to Rbp or Rsp....

How to retrieve those arguments

Answer (score 1):

[It is not possible in general case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/30/10445305.aspx).

Comment: Then how come stackwalk API able to retrieve the arguments ?

Comment: Which API do you mean? Argument retrieval is possible for functions which spills arguments into stack. But not every function will do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question then. If you have API to retrieve arguments, then answer to "how to retrieve those arguments" would be "use that API".

Comment: Hi Alex, 
stackwalk API retrieves the first 4 arguments..it is a dbghelp api...All dbghelp functions are not thread safe...I want to write a threadsafe routine...

RTLVirtualUnwind  will give me Rsp and Rbp related info...using these registers i want to get the arguments which are pushed on stack...when i looked into memory, i see arguments are not at a specific address relative to these Rsp or Rbp...there seems to be some sort of padding involved....

I wish to know if there is sure shot way to derive arguments using Rsp or Rbp

Comment: Did you read my link? There is NO 100% way to retrieve arguments for arbitrary function in Win64.

Comment: Hi Alex, 
1.If there are less than 4 arguments then that spill space can be used for some other purposes by compiler because of various optimizations -- ok i agree
Suppose there are enough number of arguments, is it still possible for compiler to use this spill space for something else other than storing arguments ?

2. Suppose the arguments are spilled to stack space
    mov [rsp+0x10], rcx
    mov [rsp+0x18], rdx
    mov [rsp+0x20], r8
    mov [rsp+0x28], r9
offsets rsp+10,rsp+18,rsp+20,rsp+28 -- are these fixed...can we predict these offsets with 100% probability ?